# 550 5.6.11 Your message contains invalid characters (bare line feed characters)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, email, smtpclient

We have an ASP.net site that sends emails using SmtpClient.  It has worked fine until recently when some of recipient SMTP servers started rejecting our messages with:

> Status code: 550 5.6.11: Your message contains invalid characters (bare line feed characters) which the email servers at <example.com> don't support.

And

> This error occurs when the email program or device used to create or send an email message **adds bare line feed characters into the message**. When bare line feed characters are included in a message, the SMTP protocol chunking feature is required to transmit the message between email servers. Chunking uses the SMTP protocol BDAT command, but the recipient's email server doesn't support the BDAT command.

Questions:
Will using a newer version of the .NET Framework (currently 4.0) resolve this issue?  If not, is there a different .NET SMTP client that will resolve this issue?

Reference:
[Fix email delivery issues for error code 550 5.6.11 in Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/non-delivery-reports-in-exchange-online/fix-error-code-550-5-6-11-in-exchange-online)

Thanks in advance!